# ¿Cómo contar registros de una tabla en base al resultado de una consulta en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

estoy tratando de hacer una consulta `Select` teniendo las siguientes tablas: `Alumno[idAlumno, nombre, grupo]` y `Asistencia[idAlumno, Fecha, estatus]`. La sentencia que quiero hacer es contar por grupo el número de asistencias y faltas ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Has intentado hacer un `select count(..)` ? Creo que falta un poco de información adicional en tu pregunta.

Comment: Muestra las estructuras de las tablas para poder ayúdate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no me equivoco con el significado del `estatus` en la tabla `Asistencia` esto debe satisfacer tus necesidades. Puedes usar `sum` o `count`

```
SELECT grupo, 
       SUM(IF( estatus = 'ASISTENCIA',1,0)) as asitencias,
       SUM(IF( estatus = 'FALTA',1,0)) as faltas
       FROM   Alumno A 
       INNER JOIN Asistencia AS
              on A.idAlumno = AS.idAlumno
       GROUP BY
              grupo
```

Comment: Muchas gracias... me sirvió mucho